# SQL Trigger Insert on Create convert column

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to insert a record into one table when a record is created in another table. I have figured out how to do this however I am trying to figure out how to change a value of one of the columns value.

In the originating table I have 'County' and in the second table I have a 'CountyID' that comes from a 'County' table. How would I take the 'County' and convert it into a 'CountyID'?

My trigger so far -

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AQB_RMS_LocationCreate] on [AVData].[dbo].[SourceSite]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO AQB_MON.[AQB_RMS].[Location]
([LocationName],[Latitude],[Longitude],[Enabled]
  ,[StreetAddress1],[StreetAddress2],[City],[CountyID],[StateAbbr],[ZipCode],[DATE_CREATED])

SELECT i.[Description],i.[Latitude],i.[Longitude],i.[Enabled]
  ,i.[StreetAddress1],i.[StreetAddress2],i.[City],i.[County],i.[StateRegion],i.[ZipCode], getdate()

from [AVData].[dbo].[SourceSite] ss
inner join inserted i on ss.SourceSiteID = i.SourceSiteID

END 

GO
```

Comment: What is the field in the `County` table that matches the data being inserted? Also, the join you currently have doesn't seem to be doing anything as none of the columns are used in the insert. Unless you are using it to check for the existence of a record in `SourceSite` table?

Comment: The `County` table just has "County" and "CountyID". I'm not sure about the joins. I use a similar trigger elsewhere and it performs the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AQB_RMS_LocationCreate] on [AVData].[dbo].[SourceSite]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO AQB_MON.[AQB_RMS].[Location]
([LocationName],[Latitude],[Longitude],[Enabled]
  ,[StreetAddress1],[StreetAddress2],[City],[CountyID],[StateAbbr],[ZipCode],[DATE_CREATED])

SELECT i.[Description],i.[Latitude],i.[Longitude],i.[Enabled]
  ,i.[StreetAddress1],i.[StreetAddress2],i.[City],C.CountyId,i.[StateRegion],i.[ZipCode], getdate()

from [AVData].[dbo].[SourceSite] ss
inner join inserted i on ss.SourceSiteID = i.SourceSiteID
inner join dbo.County C on C.County = i.County


END
```

Comment: It wrote the record but left the CountyID blank. I didn't receive any errors that I could see.

Comment: I must had typed something wrong because using the above example it now works. I did change the `inner join` to a `left join` to account for entries that are not found in my code table.